# Help with this exercise of Bourbaki General topology

Tags: general-topology, self-learning, problem-solving

The exercise is  number 6 of section 5 Open and closed maps, first chapter. It says:

> Let $S$ be the equivalence relation on the rational line $\mathbb Q$ which is obtained by identifying all the points $\mathbb Z$. Show that $S$ is closed, and that if $I$ is the relation of equality on $\mathbb Q$, then the canonical bijection of $(\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q)/(I\times S)$ onto $\mathbb Q\times (\mathbb Q/S)$ is not a homeomorphism.

The canonical bijection refers to the bijection that appears in the decomposition of a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ as $\mu:X\rightarrow X/R_f$, $h:X/R_f\rightarrow f(X)$ and $\iota:f(X)\rightarrow Y$. Here $R_f$ denotes the equivalence relation $x\sim y$ if and only if $f(x)=f(y)$.

In this problem, the $f$ should be the product map $id\times\mu_S$, where $\mu_S$ is the quotient map of $\mathbb Q$ into $\mathbb Q/S$. The equivalence relation $I\times S$ can be viewed as the induced by the product map. Moreover, in this case the injection $\iota$ is just the identity map on $\mathbb Q\times(\mathbb Q/S)$. Finally, the canonical bijection $h$ takes an element $[(x,y)]$ of the quotient and give the element $(x,[y])$.

The problem I see here is that for me the product map is closed and hence by a previous theorem this is equivalent to say that $h$ is a homeomorphism.  So, can you explain me why the maps $id\times \mu_S$ and $\mu:\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q \rightarrow \mathbb (\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q)/(I\times S)$ are not closed? (It is clear that they are not open).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a lack of $ near the end of your thread.

Comment: @LeAnhDung Thanks. Another user has corrected the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a sequence $P_n=(1/n, n)$. Clearly $A=\{P_n\}_{n>0}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is a closed subset because it is discrete. But is the image under $\mu$ or $id\times\mu_S$ closed?

Comment: For $\mu^{-1}(\mu(A))$ I have obtained the set $$\bigcup_{n\geq1}\left\{\frac{1}{n} \right\}\times\mathbb Z.$$ And I guess it is not closed because the complementary of the set $\left\{\frac{1}{n} \right\}$ contains the $0$ but I cannot insert and open ball in $0$. My computations shows that $(id\times\mu_S)^{-1}\left(id\times\mu_S(A) \right)$ gives the same set. Am I right?

Comment: @Dog_69 Your $\mu^{-1}(\mu(A))$ is correct. The argument is even simplier. This subset is not closed because $(0,0)$ is its limit point but it doesn't belong to it (note that $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is metric). For the $id\times\mu_S$ you cannot go down the same road, because $id\times\mu_S$ is not a quotient map. Or at least I don't see how it is. If you know that it is a quotient map then you are correct.

Comment: But there is a simplier argumentation: take the sequence $(1/n,[n])$ and note that is fully contained in $id\times\mu_S(A)$ but its limit which is $(0,[n])$ is not.

Comment: frakish: No, the product wasn't a quotient map, you're right. I needed your reasoning. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dog_69 actually after thinking about it again your initial idea is correct. We don't need $id\times\mu_S$ to be quotient. If image is closed then so is the preimage of the image by continuity. Sorry for the confusion.